# how can I change this mysql code to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how can i convert this code

```
$result = mysql_db_query($db, "SHOW FIELDS FROM $table") or mysql_die();
```

I don't found equivalent of function `mysql_db_query()` in mysqli

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php for the equivalent call to make a query, but there is more to it than converting just that one line. You will need to establish a connection through mysqli and fetch the results through mysqli. Also, if you are converting from the legacy mysql to mysqli, you should consider evaluating PDO as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of mysqli is quite simple actually just need to call the query function of a mysqli object, equivalent would be:

```
     //Instantiate mysqli db object        
     $sqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db'); 
     if ($sqli->connect_error)
        die ("Could not connect to db: " . $db->connect_error);
     //Make query
     $sqli->query("SHOW FIELDS FROM $table") or die("Some error " . $sqli->error);
     $sqli->close();
```